# Which Event Loop Phase Executes Ordinady JavaScript Code

Tags: node.js, event-loop

I am new to node.js and little bit confused on understanding the event-loop. As far as i know from https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/topics/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick.md, the event-loop phases only process setTimeout, setInterval, setImmediate, process.nextTick, promises and some I/O callbacks.

My question is, if i have following code:

for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++)
  ;

in which phase the above code will get executed ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, I wouldn't expect a for-loop to be considered an "event" to be processed by an event loop.

Comment: `I/O callbacks: executes almost all callbacks...`.  In node an HTTP server handling a request is I/O.

Comment: so, where will be the code get executed. Is it executed via callstack ?

Comment: The event loop is a queue.  If I'm not mistaken, these *phases* are different priority queues.

Comment: If it won't be processed by event-loop, will you consider that the code itself doesn't block the event-loop ?

Comment: The event-loop is *how* code is queued for execution.  How can you execute that code without the event-loop?

Comment: @DavinTryon so the code will be executed in the event-loop right ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by *in the event-loop*.  JavaScript code is executed on a single thread.  The single thread is coordinated by an event-loop.  The event-loop has multiple queues that are managed by priority (in phases).  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @DavinTryon hmmm still don't get your point. do you know any good diagram that shows how the event-loop actually works in nodejs ?

Comment: The event loop has descibed by Node is: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#poll

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regular JavaScript code, like the `for` loop in your example, is executed before the queues are cleared.  The first thing node will do is run your code, and will only call callbacks, timeout results, I/O results, and so on **after** your code finishes.

As an example, you could try this code:

```
fs.open('filename', 'r', () => {
  console.log('File opened.');
});

for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++);

console.log('Loop complete.');
```

No matter how big or small your loop variable, 'Loop complete' will always appear before 'File opened'.  This is because with only one thread, node can't run the callback you've supplied to the fs.open function until the loop code has finished.

Remember that there isn't a "main" thread that node keeps going back to.  Most long-running node programs will run through the code in main.js pretty quickly, and subsequent code is all going to come from callbacks.  The purpose of the initial execution is to define how and when those callbacks happen.

Answer (score 0):

In the node event loop doc (https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick), the following code is given as an example:

```
const fs = require('fs');

function someAsyncOperation(callback) {
  // Assume this takes 95ms to complete
  fs.readFile('/path/to/file', callback);
}

const timeoutScheduled = Date.now();

setTimeout(() => {
  const delay = Date.now() - timeoutScheduled;

  console.log(`${delay}ms have passed since I was scheduled`);
}, 100);


// do someAsyncOperation which takes 95 ms to complete
someAsyncOperation(() => {
  const startCallback = Date.now();

  // 10ms loop
  while (Date.now() - startCallback < 10) {
    // do nothing
  }
});
```

The loop keeps scanning according to phases and after `fs.readFile()` finishes, the poll queue is is empty, so its callback will be added and immediately executed. The callback holds a blocking 10ms loop before the timer is executed. That is why the delay will display:
`105ms have passed since I was scheduled` instead of the 100ms you might expect.

Most of your code will live in callbacks so will be executed in the **poll** phase. If not, like in your example, it will be executed before entering any phases as it will block the event loop.

The caveat are callbacks scheduled by `setImmediate` that will enter the **check** phase before resuming the poll phase in the next loop.

Answer (score 0):

The event loop tells you in which phase which parts of your "ordinary javascript code" code is executed.

So javascript code is executed **when ever the event loop finds something to do**, **no matter in which phase** the event loop currently is.

This is done synchronously, so the event loop can not go on to the next phase before the current javascript code is completely executed.

So Node.js **will only check the event loop** at all **if there is nothing to do**, i.e. if it doesn't execute javascript code already right now.

As soon as Node.js finds anything to do in one of the phases in the event loop, it will happily go back to work and **executes javascript code immediately**, and only checks the event loop again when the work is done.

So you can imagine the event loop like:

```
,-> execute javascript code in timer callbacks
|
|   execute javascript code in pending callbacks
|
|   ...
|
|   execute javascript code in check callbacks
|
`-- execute javascript code in close callbacks
```